# Frame described by locally flat metric is in general not an inerial frame - true or false?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

In general relativity there is always a **locally** flat system, for which the transformed metric is the Minkowski metric up to second order **at one point**. But this does not mean, that the system, described by the new coordinates is automatically an inertial frame. Is that right?

If this is true: why can I apply Lorentz transformation of special relativity in that metric? The metric is locally flat so SR applies - but the frame is nevertheless no inertial frame. Isn't that a contradiction, because Lorentz-transformations are valid only in inertial systems?

I'm confused...

Comment: Though it isn't obvious from the title this is effectively a duplicate of [How can locally Euclidean space of zero curvature accumulate to non-zero global curvature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/532995/how-can-locally-euclidean-space-of-zero-curvature-accumulate-to-non-zero-global)

Comment: I can transform locally always to a coordinate system, where the metric is like Minkowski metric? This would be normal coordinates, but not coordinates, which describe a free falling system. The question is: Even when I have a fixed point on earth, I can find a coordinate system which the metric is Minkowski like. But, as acceleration is not zero this is of course not an inertial system. Can I nevertheless apply special relativity in such frame?

Comment: Your metric at a fixed point would locally look like a Rindler metric not Minkowski.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tis very important to notice that you can do this at a given point, but not at any given curve. In fact, it is true that for geodesics you can define a locally flat coordinate system such that the Christoffel symbols vanish along the curve. This is compatible with the idea of the equivalence principle for $inertial$ observers.

However, for more general trajectories, it is not possible to define a such a coordinate system: the Christoffel symbols get corrections due to the acceleration of the trajectory, and these are compatible with the notion of fictious forces that are seen due to non-inertiality.

The way to analyze the problem above is by means of the Fermi normal coordinates (FNC). These are a coordinate system that is associated with a timelike trajectory and describes "what an observer undergoing this trajectory sees". In case you want learn more about this, I recommend https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0529. In any case, it is possible to show that the metric in FNC can be written locally around the curve (up to first order in acceleration and curvature) as

$$\begin{aligned}
&g_{\tau \tau}=-\left(1+2 a_{\mathrm{i}}(\tau) x^{i}+R_{0 \mathrm{i} 0 \mathrm{j}}(\tau) x^{i} x^{j}\right), \\
&g_{\tau i}=-\frac{2}{3} R_{0 \mathrm{jik}}(\tau) x^{j} x^{k} \\
&g_{i j}=\delta_{\mathrm{ij}}-\frac{1}{3} R_{\mathrm{ikjl}}(\tau) x^{k} x^{l}
\end{aligned},$$
where $\tau$ is the proper time of the trajectory (and the timelike coordinate of the FNC) and $x^i$ denote the proper distance from the trajectory, which are the spacelike trajectories of the FNC. $a(\tau)$ is the trajectories proper acceleration and $R(\tau)$ is the curvature tensor along its motion.

The Christoffel symbols to first order in acceleration and curvature then read

$$\begin{aligned}
\Gamma_{i j}^{\tau} &=\frac{1}{3}\left(R_{0 \mathrm{ijm}}+R_{0 \mathrm{jim}}\right) x^{m} \\
\Gamma_{\tau i}^{\tau} &=a_{\mathrm{i}}+R_{0 \mathrm{i} 0 \mathrm{~m}} x^{m} \\
\Gamma_{\tau \tau}^{\tau} &=0 \\
\Gamma_{j k}^{i} &=\frac{1}{3}\left(R_{\mathrm{j} \mathrm{km}}^{\mathrm{i}}+R_{\mathrm{k} \mathrm{jm}}^{\mathrm{i}}\right) x^{m} \\
\Gamma_{\tau j}^{i} &=R_{0 \mathrm{mj}}{\mathrm{j}} x^{m} \\
\Gamma_{\tau \tau}^{i} &=a^{\mathrm{i}}+R_{0}^{\mathrm{i}}{ }_{0 \mathrm{~m}} x^{m}
\end{aligned},$$
which can be seen to vanish if $a^i = 0$ (inertial motion) and $x^i = 0$ (on top of the curve).